# pycharm unresolved reference for modual strange behaviour

Tags: django, python-3.x, pycharm

I am experiencing strange behaviour in pycharm.
I am working with Django 1.8 and pycharm 4.5.4
using virtualenv pip and python 3

My pycharm complains that a module derived from an app does not exist. That is if I call: from accounts.form import .... the accounts module is underlined and pycharm says unresolved reference. There was no redline then a redline appear after a while. I have two versions of the app one before edits and one after edits. The issue is that the older one now has the redline but works and the newer version says it can find the module.

Is there some kind of bug here? I am using the same virtualenv for both.

I just can't understand what going on, rebuilt the entire website twice now and after a while this issue always appear...

Not sure if any one has experienced this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you have some python compiled files in your folder causing conflicts. Since these files are usually hidden you wouldn't have noticed it

from Pycharm right click the module and press

**"Clean python compiled files"**

or from terminal, browser to the folder and type

```
rm *.pyc
```

or from terminal recursively clean the entire project, from the project folder type

```
find . -type f -name "*.pyc" | xargs rm
```

Comment: Hi thank you for that , it will be useful in the future. It didn’t resolve my issue. To tell the truth I am always worried Im having a python 3 issue cause this doesn’t happen with python 2. So I am just going to scrap using python 3 just not skilled enough at this stage to deal with it. Thanks for the help.